# what is problem in data binding this angular code

Tags: angular, data-binding

I want to bind my code. I want that app-component using from server-element and print the element property. but this is not showing the texts in the server element array in server-element.component.ts.
what should I do?

I already add @input() to my property in server-element-componenet.ts and in chrome developer mode there is no any error and it works fine but there aren't my element array texts.
[server element component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLcSH.jpg)
[server element component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OSGG.jpg)

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: Please do **NOT** add code as links to images. Paste code directly in the question as (formatted) text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app.component.html makes no sense. You have an ngFor but you are still passing your array as an input.

Your input name is elementNew but you are using element in server.component.html. So change element for elementNew. If this doesnt fix the problem, add more code to your question. We are missing the server.component.ts